# Printing large size with OpenLayers plugin basemaps?

Tags: openlayers-2, printing, large-datasets

trying to print A0, with one of the maplayers from the openlayers plugin, the resulting print misses tiles and is corrupted. any scale i choose there's no way except (i need >= 1.50.000)

I tried to edit the network settings (timeout and number of tiles) but still the same result.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar, I've been able to export to image at 50dpi but no higher.

I am though using downloaded, local OpenStreetMap layers rather than OpenLayers.